# Change values in legend of density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How would I change the values of the legend from "2" and "3" to "Solid" and "Dotted"?

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_line(aes(x=mpg,y=cyl,linetype='2')) +
  geom_line(aes(x=mpg,y=disp,linetype='3')) + 
  scale_linetype_discrete(name = "Lines Types  aes")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_line(aes(x=mpg,y=cyl,linetype='2')) +
  geom_line(aes(x=mpg,y=disp,linetype='3')) + 
  scale_linetype_discrete(name = "Lines Types  aes", labels = c("Solid","Dotted"))
```